# How to perform aggregation on firestore collection

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with firestore for the first time and the dataset in which I have users and games data.
[image]

In every game data I've `finalScore`

[image]

 There is a foreign key in `Games` called `userID` for each game that differentiate that this game data belong to.

I want to write a function in `index.js` which can take in the `userID` and SUM all the `finalScore` and return the total score for that user.

So far what I have after searching google is:

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
    .document('Users').onWrite((change, context) => {
      // ... Your code here
    });
```

This is the first time I'm working on this and want to achieve something for which I didn't find related help. I'm working on an iOS app for which I'm using this as a backend service.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't have any aggregation queries, because they don't scale massively as Firestore requires.  If you want to find a total value among documents, you will either have to:

1. Query all the documents in the client, and sum them manually, or
2. Keep a running total over time, as each new score is known.  Then, you can query for that running total in another document when you need it.

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you :)